# How can I create an object inside a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object

I want the object to be inside the class, but I can only do it inside a function:

This is basically what I want:

```
class Foo1 {

public:
   Foo1(int a, int b) { /*stuf..*/. }

}

class Foo2 {

Foo1 foo1(2, 1); // oject here

public:
   Foo2(int a, int b) { /*stuf...*/ }

}
```

Comment: `Foo1 foo; public: Foo2(int a, int b) : foo1(2,1) { }` ?

Comment: `Foo1 foo1{2, 1};`

Comment: What means the " : " ?

Comment: I strongly prefer the uniform initialization method.

Comment: @l4x3 "_What means the " : " ?_" [What is this weird colon-member (“ : ”) syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the object and initialize it:

```
class Foo2
{
public:
    Foo1 foo1{2, 1}; // using curly brackets, object created and initialized

    // Or in the initializer list of the Foo2 constructor 
    // Foo1 foo1;
    // Foo2() : foo1(1,2){}
};
```

Let's assume your class Foo1 has 2 `int` members `a` and `b`, only for for test purposes because the object creation is the same:

```
class Foo1
{
public:
    int a, b; 
    Foo1(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {} // constructor
};
```

Test main:

```
int main()
{
    Foo2 foo2; // Foo2 object will have a Foo1 object inside

    std::cout << foo2.foo1.a << " "; // test print
    std::cout << foo2.foo1.b;        
}
```

Outupt

```
2 1
```

[**Live sample**](https://godbolt.org/z/aP35bvvYz)

Answer (score 0):

If the code that you expect to go where you write

```
//stuf...
```

is simple, duplicate the code.

If not, create a function and call the function.

#### Example (Simple)

Duplicate the code.

```
class Foo1 {

public:
   Foo1(int a, int b) { int i = 0; int j = 0; }

}

class Foo2 {

Foo1 foo1(2, 1);

public:
   Foo2(int a, int b) { int i = 0; int j = 0; }

}
```

#### Example (Not Simple)

Use a function.

```
int complexFunction() { ... }

class Foo1 {

public:
   Foo1(int a, int b) { int i = complexFunction(); }

}

class Foo2 {

Foo1 foo1(2, 1);

public:
   Foo2(int a, int b) { int i = complexFunction(); }

}
```